# How can I get system user token of another facebook business to manage their audiences?

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am working to build an application which would be able to create custom audiences for many of our clients for facebook ads. I came to know that the most suitable access token for this purpose is system user token (correct me if I am wrong). To get regular user access tokens, we can make a user go through the traditional oAuth flow, I am looking for something similar to get system user access token. How can I get it for any of my clients? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create your system users in the Business Manager of your company:

```
https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users?business_id=<YOUR_BUSINESS_ID>
```

Once you create a system user, you can generate a token for him associated with a given app.

Meanwhile, on your business settings ([as stated in the docs](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/www/530540643805698)) you can request access to an ad_account.

> Request Access to an Ad Account: If you request access to an ad
>   account in Business Manager, the admin of that Business Manager can
>   grant you permission to work on it.

Once your client gives your Business permission to work with one or more of their ad_accounts, those ad_accounts will appear in your Business Manager. (menu on the left).

At that point, when checking the profile of your system users, you can click on `assign assets` to give the system user access to pages and ad_accounts.

The token you generated for the pair [system_user,app_id] does not need to be reissued to reflect the addition of assets to which the system_user has access.